# How to input the minimum and maximum values in the input box

Tags: html, css

I want to record the minimum and maximum price of the shares of different companies daily. I am trying to use this tag

```html
<input type="number" name="number" placeholder="minprice">

<input type="number" name="number" placeholder="maxprice">
```

But I want in a single input need to enter both min and max prices of the share on the particular date.

What need to be included or changed?

Comment: Add `min` and/or `max` to your input: `<input type="number" name="number" min="1" max="5">`

Comment: What I can understand from your statement is that you want only 1 input field to log some value. So, do you want to first enter the in prices and then max price? If there's only 1 input field then it has to be in some sequence.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal Exactly. I want to input min price first and followed by the maximum price in the same input field both values separated by some '-' or 'to'.

Comment: @GirishKallihal, check my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` and `max`.

```html
<form>
<input type="number" name="number" placeholder="minprice" min="5" />
<input type="number" name="number" placeholder="maxprice" max="40" />
<input type="submit" name="Send" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **HTML  min Attribute**, your tags  should look like this

```
<input type="number" name="number" placeholder="minprice" min="1" >

<input type="number" name="number" placeholder="maxprice" max="5">
```

read docs here [min and max](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 values in one input of type "number".
You can put both values in input of type "text" and restrict with javascript on keydown or keyup which symbols can be entered in that input.

I would suggest you keep it on the UI in 2 different inputs so there is less space for user mistakes. And then behind the scenes take both of the values and combine them however you want or need.

Comment: Okay. But want to record a) Yesterday's min and max price b) Today's min and max price and want to compare those two values.

Comment: Do you want to compare min and max price of the same day? Or today's min price to yesterday's min price and the same with max price?

Comment: Do you record separately min and max price into your database?

Comment: Yes I am recording the values in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the first value `minPrice` from the input field and clear the value to accept second value `maxPrice`. Using a counter you'll know which is what.

NOTE: This will work only for first 2 clicks. You can tweak the function as per your requirements.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("save-btn");
var minPrice, maxPrice;
var count = 0;
btn.onclick = function() {
  var price = document.getElementById("share-price");
  count += 1;
  if (count == 1) {
    minPrice = price.value;
    price.value = '';
    console.log('minPrice', minPrice)
  } else if (count == 2) {
    maxPrice = price.value;
    price.value = '';
    price.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    btn.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    console.log('maxPrice', maxPrice)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter price" id="share-price" />
<button id="save-btn">Save</button>
```